# Parse json with parameters

Tags: php, json

hi i have this web service and i whant to call it with parameter with afnetworking

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
include('settings.php');
mysql_connect($host,$user,$password);
mysql_select_db($base);
mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
$patient = (int) $_POST['patient'];

$req = "select * from consultation where id_patient= $patient";
$sql=mysql_query($req);
$nn=mysql_num_rows($sql);

$items = array("items" => NULL);

while ($data=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    $items["items"][] = array(
        "id_consultation" => $data['id_consultation'],
        "id_patient" => $data['id_patient'],
        "date_consultation" => $data['date_consultation'],
        "motif_consultation" => $data['motif_consultation'],
        "taille" => $data['taille'],
        "poids" => $data['poids'],
        "tension_arterielle" => $data['tension_arterielle'],
        "pouls" => $data['pouls'],
        "temperature" => $data['temperature'],
        "observation" => $data['observation'],
        "ordonnance" => $data['ordonnance'],

    );


}
    echo json_encode($items,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

?>
```

when i call it with

```
http://localhost:8888/services/consultation.php?patient=1
```

it show me {"items":null}  can anyone help me :) thx

Comment: should be `php` tagged not `ios`

Comment: sorry but im parsing it in ios

Comment: do you have any idea about this problem

Comment: add relevant iOS code too then

Comment: im parsing with afnetworking so i only need a valid address :)

Comment: your problem is mainly `while ($data=mysql_fetch_array($sql))` , if the code does not go in the loop. your items will still be null. Now you need to debug the php code and thus question should be tagged php

Comment: it's working without parameter it show me results but i need to pas a parameter

Comment: I see no way that that script could be "working" without a parameter being passed.  The query would fail. Of course you do not handle error conditions at all, which is not good.  Try adding error handling around your database operations.

Answer (score 0):

```
$items = array("items" => array());

while ($data=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    $item = array(
        "id_consultation" => $data['id_consultation'],
        "id_patient" => $data['id_patient'],
        "date_consultation" => $data['date_consultation'],
        "motif_consultation" => $data['motif_consultation'],
        "taille" => $data['taille'],
        "poids" => $data['poids'],
        "tension_arterielle" => $data['tension_arterielle'],
        "pouls" => $data['pouls'],
        "temperature" => $data['temperature'],
        "observation" => $data['observation'],
        "ordonnance" => $data['ordonnance']
        );

    array_push($items['items'], $item);
}

echo json_encode($items);
```

try

Comment: it work thank you waki :) and thank to all of you :)

Comment: @user3127590: If that solved your problem then you should *accept* the answer by clicking on the check mark. That marks the problem as closed and gives some reputation points to you and to the author of the answer!